# Multithreading and implementing thread-safety enqueue operation

Tags: c, multithreading, queue, pthreads, semaphore

I have this queue that I implemented with semaphores to make it thread-safe. It basically does not allow multiple threads to enqueue to the queue at the same time.  Here is the enqueue function:

```
int queueEnqueue(queue* q, int* value){
    int value1;
    sem_getvalue(&(q->sem1),&value1);
    //printf("Value of semaphore is: %d\n", value1); 
    sem_wait(&(q->sem1));
    if(!queueIsFull(q)){
        q->rear = (q->rear + 1) % q->capacity;
        q->array[q->rear] = *value;
        q->size = q->size + 1;
        sem_post(&(q->sem1));
        return(1);
    }
    sem_post(&(q->sem1));
    return(0);
}
```

I have this piece of code in my main but for some reason I always get error 11 back which means "not enough resources for the thread." num_threads is 10000 and my ulimit -u is 128. Is this the problem? I was told my program should still work.

```
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++){ // run the test 10 times
        printf("\n-------Run %d-------\n", j);
        printf("====Enqueuing...");
        for(i = 0; i < num_pthreads; i++) {
            //printf("%d\n", i);
            if ((rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, enqueueThread, (void*) q))) {
                fprintf(stderr, "error: pthread_create, rc1: %d\n", rc);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            } 
        }
```

I just tested with num_threads 10 and it works fine but anything around 100 makes it throw error.

Comment: 10k threads is *far* beyond the process limits of stock unix os's. For pthreads the typical limit is 512, at least for x86 impls. If you're running x64 I've seen as high as 32k, but never had the brass to use them myself. I dunno what the problem is, but I can go strong on the advice that 10k threads is *not* the solution. Dare I ask why 10K ? I mean, because 9999 isn't enough and 10001 was just too many? What was the gating factor on settling on that number ?

Comment: It is for an assignment and I have the same confusion. Our queue is tested if it is thread safe with 10000 threads and it doesnt make sense to me. I know it is safe for 10 because I updated the num_threads but the original definition is 10000 so I dont know what to do.

Comment: Are you sure the thread pool is supposed to be 10k and not the *queue size* ceiling? That would make a lot more sense. Unless these threads are severely IO bound having such a huge number makes no sense. If they're CPU bound you really don't want more than the logical core count on the chip anyway (give or take).

Comment: Yes it is the num_threads definition. I solved my problem. It seems that there's some limitation in that system that pthread and openmp can't be used at the same time in the program. So I erased a line that made use of openmp and it works fine. I still don't understand how I can run 10000 threads though

Comment: I checked it any my system allows 3084716 threads via cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max. I thought linux treats the threads and processes in a similar way. I thought they were the same except the stack, register and pc. Apparently the number available for creation is also different